# Proof that Gale-Shapley is man optimal

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble following this proof that the Gale Shapley algorithm always outputs an optimal matching for men.

[image: screen shot]

Overall I find it hard to follow (probably because I find the notion of "optimal for men" rather vague) but in particular I get lost at "Let B be partner of Z in S". Two lines above we said A is a partner of Z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear up the definition first: to say that $S^*$ is "optimal for men" means that in $S^*$, every man is paired with the best possible woman he can possibly be with among all stable pairings.  There is nothing vague about it.

Now to address your point.  "Two lines above", we were talking about the pairing $S^*$, the pairing produced by the Gale-Shapley algorithm.  At "Let B be partner of Z in S", we are talking about a hypothetical stable pairing $S$ in which $Y$ is paired with someone better than he is paired with in $S^*$.

Comment: When is the $*$ used in these sorts of things?

Comment: * doesn't have any special meaning in this context.  (It is *not* some kind of special operation * applied to $S$.)  The author is probably (I'm guessing without looking at the source) using "variations" of the letter $S$ to denote stable pairings.  For example: $S^*, S', S_0$, etc. This kind of notation is just to remind you that whenever you see something similar to $S$, it denotes a stable pairing.  But $S$ and $S^*$ (and $S'$, etc.) are not necessarily related in any other way beyond the fact that they're both stable pairings (unless there is additional text saying so).

Comment: If you find this confusing, just imagine replacing $S^*$ by some totally unrelated symbol like $T$.

Comment: Ok I'm still confused because $S$ has the pairs $A-Y$ and $B-Z$ but then the line reads "Z has not been rejected by any valid partner at the point when Y is rejected by A". Isn't the whole point S is better than S* because A never rejects Y? It's really unclear to me when they're talking about S vs S*

Comment: "Z has not been rejected by any valid partner at the point when Y is rejected by A" is referring to the Gale-Shapley process used to produce $S^*$.  It is not referring to $S$. The pairing $S$ is a hypothetical stable pairing that is better than $S^*$ for $Y$, produced by any method, not GS.

Comment: So in summary this proof is showing that $S^*$ can't possibly be non-man-optimal, otherwise it would have an unstable pair?

Comment: The proof is showing that any pairing $S$ which purports to be better than $S^*$ (for some man), would have an unstable pair.  $S$ has the unstable pair, not $S^*$.  $S^*$ is produced by the GS algorithm and is always stable.

Comment: Thanks I finally get it. It seems like the proof can be a lot shorter, for example why do they even need $S$ or $B$? e.g. Suppose GS outputed a matching that wasn't man optimal. Let $Y$ be the first man who was rejected by a valid partner $A$. Suppose $A$ preferred $Y$ to $Z$. Since $Y$ was the first man to be rejected by a valid partner, $Z$ must prefer A over all other valid partners. Therefore if $A$ was with $Y$, this would be an unstable pair. This is a contradiction because GS has been proven to always output stable matching.

Comment: Your proof does not make sense to me, starting with "Suppose $A$ preferred $Y$ to $Z$".  $Y$ is the one getting rejected; the new candidate for $A$ should be someone she prefers over $Y$, not the other way around.  But more importantly, in order for there to be unstable pair, *both* parties should be unhappy with their current partners, so there have to be 4 people involved (the unstable pair + their current partners), which you don't seem to have here.

Comment: Also, you have to have another pairing S involved in the proof because to say that GS is not man optimal means there is *another* stable pairing in which one of the men has a better partner than in GS.

Comment: That's what I don't get. How does showing that $S$ would be unstable, show that $S^*$ is man optimal? We have proven $S$ has an unstable pair but I'm still unclear how that implies $S^*$ is man-optimal.

Comment: Because the argument applies to *any* pairing $S$ in which some man is better off in $S$ than he is in $S^*$.  We prove that any such $S$ is unstable, therefore, $S^*$ is optimal for all men among stable pairings.

Comment: I still don't get that. It seems like we're showing a more man-optimal solution can't exist, but that doesn't necessarily mean the one we have is man optimal (since possible there could be no man optimal solution).

Comment: How can that be?  First, we gave an algorithm (GS) to construct a stable pairing $S^*$.  Then, we proved that no man can do better in any other stable pairing than he does in $S^*$.  By definition, this means $S^*$ is man-optimal.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. How did you know the definition of man-optimal? After google searching the only definition I could find was "E
ach man receives best valid partner." which was a bit to condensed for me to digest.

Comment: The source you found should also define "valid partner" somewhere.  A "valid partner" in this context means that two people can be paired up in *some* stable pairing.  It is also sometimes called a "stable partner" or a "possible partner".  Maybe the original Gale-Shapley paper will help: http://cramton.umd.edu/market-design/gale-shapley-college-admissions.pdf

Comment: Hi, I am still confused after reading through the comments. I thought the definition of stable matching is that there will never be an unstable match but why in S, A and Y still matched when there exists the unstable A and Z?